# Generate a 'readonly record struct' using Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, code-analysis, .net-7.0

I can't generate a readonly record struct using Roslyn.

My code:

```cs
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;

var tree = SyntaxFactory.CompilationUnit()
    .AddMembers(
            SyntaxFactory.RecordDeclaration(
                SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.RecordKeyword),
                SyntaxFactory.Identifier("A"))
            .WithSemicolonToken(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken))
            .AddModifiers(
                        SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword),
                        SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.ReadOnlyKeyword))
            .WithClassOrStructKeyword(
                SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.StructKeyword))
            .WithParameterList(
                SyntaxFactory.ParameterList()))
    .NormalizeWhitespace();

Console.WriteLine(tree.ToFullString());

var refApis = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .Where(a => !a.IsDynamic)
    .Select(a => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(a.Location));

var options = new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary);

var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("something", new SyntaxTree[] { tree.SyntaxTree }, refApis, options);
var diag = compilation.GetDiagnostics().Where(e => e.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error).ToList();

foreach (var d in diag)
{
    Console.WriteLine(d);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

I get such a result "public readonly record struct A();"
and such an error "(1,31): error CS0106: The "readonly" modifier is invalid for this element."

Comment: This is strange. I've tried with the same syntax tree and I get the exact same compile error. However, you can also create a syntax tree using `CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText("public readonly record struct A();")` and this compiles without the error. Inspecting both syntax trees they look the same but there must be some minor difference not immediately visible that triggers the compile error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the record declaration you're creating has `SyntaxKind.RecordDeclaration` instead of `SyntaxKind.RecordStructDeclaration`. Even if you are adding the struct keyword, it doesn't change the SyntaxKind that was originally created. To fix this, you'll need to do it as follows:

```cs
            SyntaxFactory.RecordDeclaration(
                SyntaxKind.RecordStructDeclaration,
                SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.RecordKeyword),
                SyntaxFactory.Identifier("A"))
```

instead of

```cs
            SyntaxFactory.RecordDeclaration(
                SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.RecordKeyword),
                SyntaxFactory.Identifier("A"))
```